# Wireless programming support with and without MFI

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, wifi, mfi

Excuse me for asking more questions in a thread, but they are closely related.

I am going to develop a wireless (most probably BlueTooth) adapter to be attached to my medical device. I have to develop an iPhone control application that has to send/receive data between this adapter over wireless.

I want to confirm the following understandings/doubts.

1. To send/receive data between iPhone and my adapter, I need to certify my adapter as MFI and include apple authentication hardware into it. Is this the only way? Do we have any existing facility without having to get the certification and stuff like that?
2. How does the MFI process work? Timeline? and procedure in a nutshell?
3. I want to know alternatives which dont involve MFI process. Do we have enough programming support in iPhone SDK to have WiFi connection to my adapter to transfer data?

Comment: You will find a lot of information in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870029/wireless-communication-avr-based-embedded-system-and-iphone

Comment: Hi Kevin,Thank you very much for the link. But I have one more question. If we go for MFI certified Bluetooth implementation in my adapter, will this setup block Non iPhone bluetooth communication may be from a normal Bluetooth enabled mobile?

Comment: What I mean from the previous comment is - Can we have a single bluetooth based adapter device, which will support iPhone based bluetooth dataflow, and also non iPhone based bluetooth dataflow?

Comment: yes it is possible, you can design your system such that it can talk to non iphone based devices also.